# Why does only every other HTML-element react to the "click"?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Very basic - as an reaction to a "click" on the element its class should toggle. Works as long as only one eventhandler is registered. If register more than one for the other elements then only every other element would get it's class changed. I have a feeling this has to do with event-bubbling, but a feeling is not enough. I would love to know why this happens and how I can control it. So this is what I got so far:

HTML

```
<body>
<main>
    <div>
        <p>
        <a>I'm an a-element.</a>
        </p>
    </div>    
</main>     
</body>
```

CSS

```
main {
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: black;}

div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: dimgray;}

p {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: darkgray;}

a {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;}
```

JS

```
function setGold(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
}

function setup() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
    document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `click` event *bubbles*, and `e.target` is the element the event was targeted at (which is the same element, the one actually clicked, at every level). So when you click the `a` element, this happens:

- The handler on `a` toggles the class on `e.target` (the `a` element)
- The click bubbles to the `p`, and the handler on the `p` toggles the class on `e.target` (the `a` element)
- The click bubbles to the `div`, and the handler on the `div` toggles the class on `e.target` (the `a` element)
- The click bubbles to the `main`, and the handler on the `main` toggles the class on `e.target` (the `a` element)

Toggling something an even number of times takes you back where you started. :-)

If, at each level, you wanted to refer to the element you'd attached the handler to, rather than the element that the event was targeted at, you'd use `this` or `e.currentTarget`.

This may help make it clearer:

```js
function setGold(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("gold");

    console.log("event.target.tagName = " + event.target.tagName);
    console.log("event.currentTarget.tagName = " + event.currentTarget.tagName);
    console.log("this.tagName = " + this.tagName);
}

function setup() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
    document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

```css
main {
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: black;}

div.x (.as-console) {
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: dimgray;}

p.x {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: darkgray;}

a.x {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="x">
        <p class="x">
        <a class="x">I'm an a-element.</a>
        </p>
    </div>    
</main>
```

*(The reason I added classes to your elements and the CSS is that otherwise, your CSS impacted the in-snippet console.)*

If your goal is to toggle *just* the element that was clicked, I'd take advantage of the fact that `click` bubbles and use just a single handler on `main`, having it toggle `e.target`'s class:

```
function setGold(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
}

function setup() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
}
```

```js
function setGold(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
}

function setup() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

```css
main {
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: black;}

div (.as-console) {
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: dimgray;}

p {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: darkgray;}

a {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        <p>
        <a>I'm an a-element.</a>
        </p>
    </div>    
</main>
```

If you want to filter that to only toggle `main`, `div`, `p`, and `a` but not (say) `span`, you can use [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to see if the element matches a CSS selector:

```
function setGold(event) {
    if (event.target.matches("a, p, div, main")) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
    }
}
```

```js
function setGold(event) {
    if (event.target.matches("a, p, div, main")) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
    }
}

function setup() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].addEventListener("click", setGold);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

```css
main {
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: black;}

div (.as-console) {
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: dimgray;}

p {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: darkgray;}

a {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;}

.gold {
    background-color: gold;}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        <p>
        <a>I'm an a-element.</a>
        <span>I'm a span, I don't toggle</span>
        </p>
    </div>    
</main>
```

---

Side note: The `load` event happens **very** late in the page load cycle and is almost never the right place to set up click handlers on the page. Instead, put your `script` tags at the end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and do the setup immediately. All the elements defined by the HTML above the tag will exist at that point. More in [the YUI Guidelines](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful! I just wonder what you mean by putting the script tags at the end of the body. I get that it is about how fast something loads but of course I want to keep structure (HTML) and function (JS) seperate. So I wonder which part of my JS I should put within the HTML file?

Comment: @Nat_ - Yes, keep them separate -- and put the `script` tags that refer to your `.js` files at the end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag, as I said above. See also the link, which is mostly about loading from files (not inline script).

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.stopPropagation();`

```
function setGold(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.target.classList.toggle("gold");
}
```

Check this for more reference
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp